# preferExternal mean the same as USB storage - Andorid memory structure?

Tags: android, linux, unix, memory, memory-management

I've read the `documentation` and general info about the `android memory management` and imo there is information overflow.

What I want to do is to simply put the file on the device which I would be read later from `application`.

When I plug in device to PC and select "**Open the USB Storage device**" it mounts two new drives to my **PC**. One is the **external SD(xGB) card** with filetree:

```
drwx------ 2 user user  32768 gru  6 09:38 100ANDRO
drwx------ 2 user user  32768 lis 14 17:15 folder
drwx------ 2 user user  32768 sty  8 00:08 DCIM
drwx------ 2 user user  32768 lis 11 16:47 LOST.DIR
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 501513 sty 10 21:54 varnish.log
```

and the second one is volume AFAIK the part of flash memory containing:

```
drwx------ 2 user user  32768 lip 10  2014 100ANDRO
drwx------ 2 user user  32768 lip 10  2012 Alarms
drwx------ 2 user user  32768 gru  6 09:41 Allevents
drwx------ 3 user user  32768 maj 27  2014 Android
drwx------ 2 user user  32768 cze 20  2014 AndroidAssistant_appbackup
drwx------ 2 user user  32768 cze 20  2014 App_Backup_Restore
drwx------ 2 user user  32768 sty 10 21:36 apps_backup
drwx------ 3 user user  32768 sty  9 21:03 Audio
drwx------ 3 user user  32768 cze 20  2014 backups
drwx------ 2 user user  32768 paź 16 01:59 baidu
drwx------ 3 user user  32768 maj 20  2014 BarcodeScanner
drwx------ 2 user user  32768 gru  6 09:40 bluetooth
drwx------ 3 user user  32768 sie 17 11:31 CamelDroid
drwx------ 2 user user  32768 sty 10 21:49 Contact
drwx------ 4 user user  32768 gru  6 09:39 DCIM
drwx------ 2 user user  32768 gru 19 00:02 Document
drwx------ 7 user user  32768 sty  3 08:12 Download
drwx------ 3 user user  32768 sie  4 22:13 gameloft
drwx------ 4 user user  32768 maj 31  2014 gokeyboard
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  32890 sty  7 21:44 GPS.LOG
drwx------ 2 user user  32768 gru  8 00:52 Ketchapp_SH
drwx------ 7 user user  32768 maj 27  2014 KingsoftOffice
drwx------ 2 user user  32768 mar  3  2014 Reaper
drwx------ 2 user user  32768 gru  6 09:42 LOST.DIR
drwx------ 2 user user  32768 wrz  9 14:08 mapbox_tiles_cache
drwx------ 4 user user  32768 cze 19  2014 mdm
drwx------ 3 user user  32768 lut 14  2014 media
drwx------ 2 user user  32768 lip 10  2012 Movies
drwx------ 2 user user  32768 lip 10  2012 Music
drwx------ 2 user user  32768 gru 18 08:50 Notifications
drwx------ 3 user user  32768 sie 21 17:40 osmdroid
drwx------ 2 user user  32768 gru 19 00:02 Others
drwx------ 2 user user  32768 mar  6  2014 pers
drwx------ 2 user user  32768 gru 19 00:02 Picture
drwx------ 4 user user  32768 lis 25 02:36 Pictures
drwx------ 2 user user  32768 lip 10  2012 Podcasts
drwx------ 2 user user  32768 paź  8 22:43 Ringtones
drwx------ 2 user user  32768 sie  7 17:55 SUSdownload
drwx------ 2 user user  32768 lip 25 07:33 System Volume Information
drwx------ 2 user user  32768 gru  8 00:48 TempImages
drwx------ 3 user user  32768 paź 22 16:22 tmp
drwx------ 2 user user  32768 wrz 24 08:02 TuneIn Radio
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 501513 sty 10 21:26 varnish.log
drwx------ 2 user user  32768 gru 19 00:02 Video
drwx------ 4 user user  32768 paź 22 16:29 VoiceChangerWE
drwx------ 2 user user  32768 lip  7  2014 well
```

where only the:

```
drwx------ 3 user user  32768 maj 27  2014 Android
```

directory seems to contain sort of applications where are package names like:

```
 ...
    drwx------ 3 user user  32768 sty  3 08:13 com.adobe.reader
    drwx------ 3 user user  32768 gru 16 07:55 com.android.browser
    drwx------ 3 user user  32768 mar  3  2014 com.android.gallery3d
    drwx------ 3 user user  32768 mar  3  2014 com.android.providers.media
    drwx------ 3 user user  32768 sie 15 23:07 com.android.vending
    drwx------ 2 user user  32768 cze 22  2014 com.bluemonbr
    ...
```

but unfortunately I could not find here the application installed from eclipse even If I set `installLocation` in manifest for **preferExternal** or **internalOnly**.

The best would be to put this file under the same directory as apk, but if it is not possible I would put it for tests anywhere.

The question is how to1 access this file If I put the file under one of two mentioned before memories.

Recently tried different options which return different values (in comment):

```
    Environment.getDataDirectory(); // /data
    Environment.getDownloadCacheDirectory(); // /cache
    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); // /storage/sdcard0
    Environment.getExternalStorageState(); // mounted
    Environment.getRootDirectory(); // /system
    getExternalCacheDir(); // /storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.schibsted/cache
    getCacheDir(); // /data/data/com.schibsted/cache
    getCallingPackage(); // null
    getFilesDir(); // /data/data/com.schibsted/files
```

and those paths looks weird regarding to those shown in PC browser.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

> but unfortunately I could not find here the application installed from eclipse even If I set installLocation in manifest for preferExternal or internalOnly.

That is because the `Android/` directory on [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) has nothing to do with either of those settings. Your app's directory in the `Android` directory will be created when you use `getExternalFilesDir()` or `getExternalCacheDir()` methods, available on any `Context` (e.g., your `Activity`).

> and those paths looks weird regarding to those shown in PC browser.

Most of those have nothing to do with external storage.

Comment: But from documentation about getExternalFilesDir() is "External files are not always available: they will disappear if the user mounts the external storage on a computer or removes it." So how can I access the file that we put on card from PC ?

Comment: @Jakub: [External storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) is not [removable storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). On modern Android devices, external storage is usually available to apps all the time, because it is part of the on-board flash, typically on the same partition as is [internal storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).